# C# Unity - Changing Sprite From Sprite Sheet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, sprite-sheet

I have started working on a new game and I want to make letters from a sprite sheet that change given the letter or number I give it. I created a numbers only sprite sheet in Photoshop just to test it and imported it into Unity as a Sprite. Then in a script I did this:

```
public string currLetter;

public string lettersName;

Sprite[] lettersAll;

void Awake () {

    lettersAll = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("Textures/" + lettersName);
}

void Update () {

    switch (currLetter) {

    case "0":
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = lettersAll[0];
        break;

    case "0":
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = lettersAll[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

---

I am getting an error in the switch statement where if it's for example number 1, it says that the array index is out of range and when I set the lettersAll to public it had 0 sprites. What am I doing wrong ? I have been trying to fix this all day but nothing works :/

---

Update:
Image of Sprite Sheet:

[image]

Comment: It looks like `Resources.LoadAll` is failing. You can prove this by doing `Debug.Log(lettersAll .Length);` under the `Resources.LoadAll` function. Let me know the sult of that log. Also, what directory did you put the Textures? Also, select the Texture and put a picture of the Import Settings for it.

Comment: The Textures folder is in Projects/Project Name/Assets/ and the Import Settings only worth mentioning is that I changed it to a Sprite & set the Sprite Mode to Multiple so I can cut letters everything else is at deffault

Answer (score 0):

Is your spritesheet under "Resources" folder?
For your case the sprite file should be under "Resources/Textures/"

Updated: 
I was able to duplicate the issue and solved it by making sure the following things are correct:

1. Spritesheet under /Resources folder
2. The spritesheet you are loading does have multiple sprites inside. If you see the screenshot posted here, spritesheet A,B,C,D
   will not be loaded because they have no sprites inside, even though
   the mode is set to multiple. Spritesheet E will be loaded correctly

[image: Spritesheet image]

Comment: Didn't work :/ I tried putting Assets instead of Resources but nothing works

Comment: Nothing seem to work... I literally tried everything I could find... There are no compiler errors but when I test the game I get the Array Index Out Of Range and there is nothing under lettersAll

Comment: Can you post any settings you have, so it will be easier for anyone to provide useful feedbacks

Comment: sure, what do you need ?

Comment: 1.so your spritesheet has any sprites like the screenshot shown above?
2. Have you tried other spritesheets to see if you can duplicate the same issue?

Comment: I haven't tried with other spritesheets but I have tried renaming it which removed the whole sprite sheet and then had to make it again. Image is in post update

Answer (score 0):

Sprites of sprite sheet can't be accessed like this, as the sprite sheet itself is a texture.

> Unity treats it like a texture internally, while giving you access to make it multiple and break it which is only accessed by the assigned reference.

I would recommend don't place your images in Resources, as it loads immediately at the start of the game, instead of the load at need. 
Try [***UI Sprite Manager***](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/89387) which follows this